# Nginx rewrite - not working

Tags: nginx

I have simple nginx rewrite I can't get to work.

I have this url:

https://example.com/accessories/3427-tote-bag-grey-212345050033.html

I want to redirect to:

https://example.com/dk/accessories/3427-tote-bag-grey-212345050033.html

My nginx config:

```
location / {
  index /index.php;

  rewrite ^/dk/$1/$2.html /$1/$2.html last;
 }
```

any idea want is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

`$1` and `$2` are used for captures. You have to use pattern to with groups to create captures

Try below

```
location / {
  index /index.php;

  rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+).html$ /dk/$1/$2.html last;
 }
```

Or you can do something like below

```
location / {
  index /index.php;
  location /accessories/ {
     alias <yourroot>/dk/accessories/;
  }
 }
```

Comment: should your rewrite rule be other way around? `rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+).html$ /dk/$1/$2.html last;`

Comment: @abskmj, yes indeed. Thanks!

Comment: Index should always be `index index.php;`